# How to write constructor with boolean in java?

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

My code looks like this:

```
public class Cell {

    private boolean north;
    private boolean east;
    private boolean south;
    private boolean west;

    /** Construct a Cell, using the parameters given to initialize
     * the wall instance variables.
     * 
     * @param north
     * @param south
     * @param east
     * @param west
     */
    public Cell(boolean north, boolean east, boolean south, boolean west) {
       ?
    }
```

How can I write a constructor with boolean? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think a boolean would be any different to anything else?

Comment: You appear to be using an IDE, why not let the IDE fill in the code?

Comment: The "issue" you might facing is, that you declared your parameters with the same names as your member variables. Though your member variables will be shadowed. To access them use `this.north` or rename either the parameters or members.

Comment: Aside from main question, why do you have four booleans to describe direction? In old days you would have numeric constants like `public final int NORTH = 1, EAST = 2, SOUTH = 3, WEST = 4;` and let your constructor accept `int direction`. Now you can use `enum` for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: A constructor (or any method) which takes lots of parameters of the same type is error-prone, as it is easy to swap two parameter values without noticing (was the order NESW, or NSEW?).  A [builder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) might be an alternative to consider.

Comment: @Pshemo your comment, at a glance, makes it look like you are advocating int constants. I would emphasize using enum (and enum set), with the ints being an aside for historical interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boolean` is not different, You can initialize them similar to other types like the following:
You have to use the keyword `this` (i.e to resolve shadowing) to refer to the field variables because the parameter variables have same names like the fields.

```
public Cell(boolean north, boolean east, boolean south, boolean west) {
  this.north = north;
  this.east=east;
  this.south=south;
  this.west=west;
}
```